# Make sum K with N coins

Tags: algorithm

Given N coins of denominations A[1],A[2]...A[n] where each A[i] is unique and their are infinite coins of each denomination.Also their can be at most 15 kind of coins which mean N<=15.

Now we need to distribute these coins such that total sum of all distributed coins become K.
**Two distributions are different if sequence of distribution is different that means if we need to make sum 8 then 2,3,2 is different distribution from 2,2,3.**

We need to find count of these distributions.

How this can be done in efficient way as K can go up to 10^18 though N and A[i] are both less than or equal to 15.

Example : Let K=19 and N=2 and denominations be [4,5] then here answer will be 4 as 4 possible ways are : [5,5,5,4], [5,5,4,5], [5,4,5,5] and [4,5,5,5].

Approach 1: I know about Coin problem and think it can help.But not sure how to modify it.

Comment: We have http://cs.stackexchange.com/ for such questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `C[K]` be the number of ways to make total `K`. We have a linear homogeneous recurrence

```
C[K] | K <  0 = 0
     | K == 0 = 1
     | K >  0 = sum from j=1 to N of C[K - A[j]].
```

This is not the recurrence for the usual coin change problem because **this is not the usual coin change problem**.

Let `M = max from j=1 to N of A[j]`. Then there's a matrix `L` such that, for all `K`,

```
L [C[K - 1]] = [C[K]        ]
  [...     ]   [...         ]
  [C[K - M]]   [C[K - M + 1]].
```

For, e.g., `A = [1, 3, 4]`, this matrix `L` is

```
[1 0 1 1]
[1 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 0].
```

The first row has ones in columns `A[j]` for `j=1` to `N` (or, if there are distinguishable coins with the same value, higher numbers). The other rows have ones just below the main diagonal.

```
[1 0 1 1] [C[3]] = [C[3]        + C[1] + C[0]] = [C[4]]
[1 0 0 0] [C[2]]   [C[3]                     ]   [C[3]]
[0 1 0 0] [C[1]]   [       C[2]              ]   [C[2]]
[0 0 1 0] [C[0]]   [              C[1]       ]   [C[1]]
```

To skip forward quickly in the sequence to `K`, use [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) to compute `L^K`, then multiply by the initial conditions vector `[C[0] ... C[-M + 1]]' = [1 0 ... 0]'` and return the first entry (i.e., the upper left entry of the matrix power).

Comment: Can you please explain a test case ?Am not getting it.How are you making the matrix ?

Comment: Also whats this initial condition vector ?

Comment: How for A = [1, 3, 4], this matrix L is

[1 0 1 1]
[1 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 0].?Also can you please explain your recurrence?

Comment: @user3840069 Expanded my answer slightly.

Comment: Why [C[3]] = [C[3]        + C[1] + C[0]] = [C[4]] ?I mean you are doing for [1,3,4] right ?

Comment: @user3840069 The first inequality isn't valid, because you left out the matrix-vector multiplication. The second holds because, to make 4, you can start with a 1-coin and make 3, a 3-coin and make 1, or a 4-coin and make 0.

Comment: Ohh now i see.Your calculations depend on precalculated C[i]'s ? Just last thing how are you calculating C array?

Comment: @user3840069 There's an algorithm that computes `C` entry by entry by applying the recurrence repeatedly, but it's too slow to get to `10^18` in a reasonable amount of time. The approach that I'm suggesting doesn't compute `C` at all (well, not as such anyway); it computes a [matrix power](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixPower.html) of `L` and returns one of the entries.

Comment: Almost got it.Tell me if am right for N=2 and [4.5] the matrix is [0 0 0 1 1] [1 0 0 0 0] [0 1 0 0 0] [0 0 1 0 0] [0 0 0 1 0] ?

Comment: Also tell initial vector for my above mentioned test case?

Comment: @user3840069 For this problem it's always `[C[0] C[-1] ... C[-M + 1]] = [1 0 ... 0]` regardless of the coin denominations. For other recurrences, the exact values of the base cases may be different.

Comment: You mean whatever be input its always going to be [1 0 0 0 ...0] ?

Comment: @user3840069 Yes. There's one way to make zero, and none to make a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

suppose `K` is `10^18` and `A = [1,2]`. counting only the answers of type `[1,1,.....2],[1,1,......2,1]` you will have `10^18-1` such arrays you will have to return. So I conclude that by the constraints you have presented this problem is unsolvable by a computer, due to the time and space complexity.